# Does this outwit Rosser's trick?

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic

Reading about Rosser's trick made me instantly curious about the following question: Can we devise a logic (which semantically encapsulates useful maths - define that as you will) in which for any theorem $T$, the shortest proof of $T$ is the same length as the shortest proof of the negation of $T$ **EDIT**: ***...if that negation is provable in T***?

A side reason why I'm interested in this is that philosophically I'm a big believer in Heraclites equality of opposites.  A starting point of the above logic could be that the definition of the universe is the same as the definition of the empty set.  This may seem counterintuitive but it's really quite beautiful because it means that any set is equivalent to its complement in the universe.  The implication of this is that objects are not so much the contents of their boundaries, rather they **are** their boundaries.  The boundary can be thought of as the unity of what is inside and outside and therefore all defined things are in identity with their definition.  Seeing Rosser's trick earlier today appealed to this concept somewhat because in this universe, I think Rosser's trick would not be possible.

Does that check out in a formal way or is it just nonsense?  Does it outwit the supposed theorem:  *"Any consistent, recursively axiomatized theory T in the language of arithmetic which extends Q is incomplete."*?

Comment: A theory that can proof a theorem and its opposite can prove everything and is therefore utterly useless. I am not sure what you are after , but it is nonsense that some proven theorem AND its negation can be true at the same time.

Comment: Not with paraconsistent logics, @Peter.

Comment: @Shaun And what is the merit of this logic ? Why should anyone use it , if it leads to nonsense ?

Comment: It doesn't,  @Peter. Error correcting codes can be understood with paraconsistent logics.

Comment: See [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/11663081.2019.1656393), @Peter

Comment: And [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-32168-4_9), @Peter

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> Can we devise a logic in which for any theorem $$, the shortest proof of $T$ is the same length as the shortest proof of the negation of $$

Then you asked specifically:

> Does it outwit the supposed theorem: "Any consistent … theory …”

The standard definition of “consistent” is that, there is *no* $T$ for which both $T$ and its negation are provable.  Since you want both $T$ and its negation to be provable for *all* $T$, your theory is not consistent, and Rosser has nothing to say about it.

Inconsistent theories are generally disregarded because, except in very unusual contexts, they are practically useless.  The reason we study logic and construct proofs is because we hope to gain some assurance that the theorems we prove are *true*. An inconsistent system provides easy proofs of all statements, both the true ones and the false ones. This is not of any conceivable use.

---

Consider this example.  The engineering firm we work for has contracted to design a bridge.  I determine that our bridge will collapse if its dead weight exceeds 14 million tonnes. I ask you to calculate the bridge's dead weight and compare it with 14,000,000 tonnes.  This you do, and you come back to me saying:

> I have proved that the bridge's weight does not exceed 14,000,000 tonnes.

I am pleased, but then you continue:

> But I have also proved that the bridge's weight **does** exceed 14,000,000 tonnes, and moreover the two proofs are exactly the same length!

Do this enough and management will invite you to pursue the Heracleitan equality of opposites on your own time.

Comment: (+1). This is what I also said , but some mathematicians seem to insist that such a "logic" is useful. I still agree to this answer.

Comment: I found Graham Priest"s book _In Contradiction_ interesting and thoughtful. You might  also.  But I don't think pataconsistent logic is necessary to answer this question.

Comment: I unwittingly implied that theorems and their negation are equivalent as theorems, thereby unwittingly implying that for any true theorem, its negation would be true. I guess what I should have written, is that for any theorem, its negation **if it exists** is the same length. Is that a reasonable edit for me to make to the question, which would avoid the problem you highlight, while preserving the essence of the question about circumventing Rosser's trick?

Comment: In the absence of a reply I've added that edit and petitioned to reopen the question.

Comment: I didn't reply because I think further discussion is unlikely to be productive or satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about the logic part, but you might be interested in Kolmogorov complexity theory. It is not related to logic, but has a very similar concept to what you describe.

If by a "theorem" you would mean any finite string $S$ of bits, and by a "proof", a program in an arbitrary but *fixed* "programming language" $L$ that produces it (the complexity is then the proof length), then the result $\tau(S)$ of an *arbitrary* algorithmic transformation $\tau$ has *about the same* complexity ($+O(1)$ that does not depend on $S$, only on $\tau$). Surprisingly, this impreciseness still allows to build a large theory that *does not depend on the choice of $L$*, and this "invariance" (asymptotical) under algorithmic transformations is one of its cornerstones.

You can convert a theorem $T$ (a string of symbols) to a bit string by rewriting it in $\LaTeX$ and encoding it in ASCII, and recover $T$ vice versa. Under this process, $T \mapsto \neg(T)$ clearly corresponds to an algorithmic transformation of bit strings.

Comment: In another context I would agree that this would be a good suggestion. But this person's problem, in my opinion, is that they are trying to ask questions about a field in which their background is impoverished.  They're asking questions about Rosser's theorem, when they don't know the definitions of the basic terms in the statement of Rosser's theorem.  I think that for this person to make progress, they need to back up and learn more fundamentals, rather than to press forward and learn more new things that they will misunderstand.

Comment: @MJD I know many maths teachers don't share this view, but I am of the view one can move forward at *map-level* (or at say 20,000 feet) by scanning the landscape and asking locals, before getting your machete out and hacking your way through the jungle. I totally accept that an explorer must ultimately be capable of making their way through the jungle themselves. I am apt to do that, but it is my style to spend much more time in the "intuition" zone before rolling my sleeves up, than most.